# Does clEnqueueMapBuffer used with CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR buffer return the same host pointer?

Tags: c, opencl

My understanding is that if I set up a `cl_mem` object using `clCreateBuffer` using the flag `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`, that block of memory is now in the control of the device.

If I wish to alter that memory on the host in some way, I should first map the memory using `clEnqueueMapBuffer`, which returns a pointer.

Is the pointer that is returned guaranteed in this case to be the same pointer that was used to create the buffer (i.e. that I passed to `clCreateBuffer` initially), albeit with type `void *`?

By extension, if I now wish to return control of the memory to the device, can I call `clEnqueueUnmapMemObject` and use the original pointer used to create the buffer for the *`mapped_pointer`* argument?

Edit: Further investigation would suggest that the pointer would clearly not be the same if a non-zero offset is used when calling `clEnqueueMapBuffer`. Therefore, the questions above are in the case when I *do* set a zero offset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't answer your question with a straight yes or no, but I can give some pointers (no pun intended).

I didn't find in the standard anything that guaranty that the two pointers should actually be the same. However, in the section 5.2.4 of the standard there is a interesting note stating:

> If the buffer object is created with CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR set in mem_flags, the following will be true:
>
> - The host_ptr specified in clCreateBuffer is guaranteed to contain the latest bits in the region being mapped when the clEnqueueMapBuffer command has completed.
> - The pointer value returned by clEnqueueMapBuffer will be derived from the host_ptr specified when the buffer object is created.

I don't know why you asked that question but at least with the first bullet point you know that you can use the 'original' pointer while the region is mapped.

I found the second bullet point quite unclear but maybe it's because I'm not a native. You might have a better understanding of it than me. Still it seems to me that it **might** suggest a yes to your question...

Finally I found out in the chapter 10 of ["Heterogeneous Computing with OpenCL"](http://www.heterogeneouscompute.org/?page_id=7) a footnote (page 200) stating:

> Note that CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR guarantees that when map is called on
> the buffer, the passed pointer becomes the host pointer returned by
> map. Data is still only valid at the host pointer between calls to map
> and unmap.

Of course this note is about CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR and not CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, and it doesn't indicate the relevant standard section. Still, it's very tempting to assume it's the case for CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR too.

Comment: Really useful, thanks. I would infer from the second point from 5.2.4 of the standard that if the offset is non-zero, then it's an offset from that pointer. Though I wonder if there is anything subtle in alignment issues...

Comment: I'd actually go so far as to say yes. The pointer is only *derived* because there is `offset` specified. But if `offset` is zero, then the pointer is the same.